# how to move a dom position on a text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have:

```
<span id="root">hello , How are you?<span id="move">Ahmad</span></span>
```

I basically want to move the element with ID `move` after the word `Hello` (after 5 characters), So that I get `Hello Ahmad, How are you?`

Is there anyway to achieve what I need in javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```js
let root = document.getElementById("root");
let movable = document.getElementById("move");

root.textContent =
  root.firstChild.textContent.slice(0, 6) +
  movable.textContent +
  root.firstChild.textContent.slice(6);
root.remove(movable);

console.log(root);
```

```html
<span id="root">hello , How are you?<span id="move">Ahmad</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much you're allowed to do.

**Purely JS:**

```
var child = document.getElementById("move");
var root = document.getElementById("root");

root.removeChild(child);
root.innerHTML = "Hello " + child.outerHTML + root.innerHTML.split("hello")[1].trim();
```

**JS + Minor HTML Update**

HTML:

```
<span id="root">Hello <span id="ending">, How are you?</span><span id="move">Ahmad</span></span>
```

JS

```
var ending = document.getElementById("ending");
var moveable = document.getElementById("move");

ending
    .parentNode
    .insertBefore
    (
        ending.parentNode.removeChild(moveable), 
        ending
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

found another easier way for it would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var move = $('#move');
  var text = $('#root').text();
  $('#root').text(text.substring(0, 6));
  $('#root').append(move);
  $('#root').append(text.substring(6, text.length-5));
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/t6dLkav4/5/